# gradle dependency to use Latlng in java project

Tags: java, android, gradle

I want to use the Latlng class in my java project. 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng

Can someone tell me the gradle dependency for that.

Answer (score 3):

Um, well, that class would appear to be part of the Maps V2 library given its Java package, and so the dependency is on the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps` artifact from the Google Repository.

However, loading in *all* of Maps V2, just for the tiny `LatLng` class, would not seem to be a wise move. If you are going to be integrating more of Maps V2, then OK, but if you just want a class to track two `double` values, it would make more sense to write your own or use [the Android SDK's own `Location` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html).

Comment: I could not find it in maven repository. Can you please give link for that in mvnrepository.

Comment: @Kuldeep: The repository is on your hard drive. I cannot provide a link to your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? From the Java package, it looks like this is from the Maps V2 API, not the location API.

Comment: Yes, I have used the Places API with LatLng class just by including this artifact, so it is contained within location api

Comment: Ah, that's because `play-services-location` depends upon `play-services-maps` (which seems backwards, but it's how Google set up their artifacts...). If you look at the JAR inside the `play-services-location` AAR, you will not see this class, but it is inside the `play-services-maps` AAR.